# Specify search results based on multiple categories in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, filtering, categories

I'm currently using Media Category Library, a plugin for Wordpress which allows a user to add categories to their media, and then search their media based on these categories using a frontend search form.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-category-library/

After testing it, I realised that if you clicked multiple categories on the checklists it generates, It will find **all** media from those categories, and not media that has been assigned to those multiple catgories.

Take this example.

- Media 1        categories="Cats"
- Media 2        categories="Dogs"
- Media 3        categories="Dogs, Cats"

If I ticked Cats and Dogs, I would only want it to find Media 3, and ignore the other two. Yet at the moment, if I ticked Cats and Dogs in the list of checkboxes, it would return all 3 pieces of media.

These two SQL queries appear to be where the issue is, but after trying many different things, I cannot find a solution to my problem.

```
        // create sub query, get term_taxonomy


        $sub_sql = "SELECT x.term_taxonomy_id FROM " . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . " AS x " .
                "INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->terms . " AS t ON x.term_id = t.term_id WHERE " .
                "t.slug IN(" . implode( ",", $selected_terms ) . ")";       


        // main query that uses subquery

        $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_mime_type, p.post_excerpt, p.post_date FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " AS p " . "LEFT JOIN " . $wpdb->term_relationships . " AS r ON p.ID = r.object_id " .
                "WHERE r.term_taxonomy_id IN($sub_sql) AND p.post_type='attachment'";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to change your 1st query to equals.

```
$sub_sql = "SELECT x.term_taxonomy_id FROM " . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . " AS x " .
        "INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->terms . " AS t ON x.term_id = t.term_id WHERE " .
        "t.slug like '" . implode(",", $selected_terms) . "%'";
```

There is a space after the "," in the implode because your example has a space if it is not needed just remove it.

Updated code. If you make sure the terms are in a specific order you could use like. To exclude singles and pull all multiples.

Comment: I've just tried that out, and it hasn't worked :/ Wouldn't that look only for things with the exact categories of "Dogs, Cats" anyway? If we had Media 4 in the example I gave, which had categories "Dogs, Cats, Horses", I'd still want that to be found if people only checked the boxes for Cats and Dogs

Comment: So you are wanting it to pull multiple items, but not singular?

Comment: Updated code if your Dogs, Cats, Horses are always in that order you could use like to pull the values of dogs, cats and dogs, cats, horses.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain exactly what I want, I just want the search narrowing down based on the categories they check. Similar to how on Amazon if I click Computer Monitors, and 22", I'd want it to find all the 22" Monitors.     This is for a Health and Safety Company, so I'd want the user to be able to click "Fire" and "Risk Assessments" and it to find all the Risk Assessments relating to fire, which could be 1 pdf, or could be 20 pdfs

Comment: Are you wanting to pull something like related ranking? What is the closest? Probably need more information.

Comment: The frontend search is like this http://imgur.com/s3Kfx6E  They click to check some categories, and it narrows down their search. In the picture, if they had clicked "COSHH" and "BCC", I would want the document shown to appear in the list. Same as if they had clicked "BCC", "COSHH" and "Risk Assessments", or just "COSHH" on it's own.

Comment: So if they click on dogs and cats why don't u want those pulled? You only want "dogs, cats" Pulled, but yet if they click on dogs, cats you want that pulled plus dogs, cats, horses? Why do you have Media 3 instead of pulling just from media 1 and media 2 both? Kind of need more information

Comment: Ahh, it appears formatting may have messed up what I'm explaining. In the example in the original post. Media 1 has been assigned the category "Cats", Media 2 has been assigned the category "Dogs", Media 3 has been assigned the categorIES "Cats" & "Dogs". These were just examples of the way I may have the media stored in my database. Which is why in that example if I clicked "Cats" And "Dogs" I would only want Media 3 to appear in my search results, since Media 1 was assigned the category "Dogs", but not "Cats". Is this the information you needed?

Comment: How many of these categories do you have? Cause you may need to create an array and pull specific medias based off the search checks.

Comment: There'll be around 50 categories in all, but each piece of individual media will have a max of 3 assigned categories. $selected_terms, which is used in the queries, is an array, it is just an array of the checkboxes they have ticked